# jquery thumbnail slider loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, thumbnails

I have created a thumbnail carousel and cannot figure out how to get it stop once it gets to the last thumbnail. At the end of the thumbnail the user should only be able to click on the #left .arrow to back through the thumbnails.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Here is the HTML

```
            <img id="bigimage" src="images/CHENCH1.jpg" alt="City1" title="City1">

            <div id="thumbnail-wrapper">
                <a id="left" class="arrow"><img src="images/leftb.png"></a>
                        <div id="thumbnails">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image1" src="images/CHENCH1.jpg" alt="City1" title="City1">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image2" src="images/CHENCH2.jpg" alt="City2" title="City2">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image3" src="images/CHENCH3.jpg" alt="City3" title="City3">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image4" src="images/CHENCH4.jpg" alt="City4" title="City4">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image5" src="images/CHENCH5.jpg" alt="City5" title="City5">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image6" src="images/CHENCH6.jpg" alt="City6" title="City6">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image7" src="images/CHENCH7.jpg" alt="City7" title="City7">

                            <img class="thumb" id="image8" src="images/CHENCH1.jpg" alt="City8" title="City8">
                        </div>
            <a id="right" class="arrow"><img src="images/rightb.png"></a>
            </div>



        </div><!--product-->
```

And here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".thumb").click(function(){
        $("#bigimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        $("#bigimage").attr("title", $(this).attr("title"));
        $("#bigimage").attr("alt", $(this).attr("alt"));
    });
//move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button

    $("#right").click(function(){

        $("#thumbnails").animate({
            "left": "-=178px"

        },500);

    });


$("#left").click(function(){

    $("#thumbnails").animate({
        "left": "+=178px"

    },500);

});
```

});

HEre is the CSS:

```
#product{
    float: left;
    width: 560px;
}
#rightinfo{
padding-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#rightinfo h1{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.thumb {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

#thumbnail-wrapper {
    width: 546px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 7px;
}

#thumbnails {
    width: 1066px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

#bigimage {
     padding: 20px;
    width: 560px;
    display: block;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}

#left {
    left: 0;
}

#right {
    left: 525px;
}
```

Here is a link to the site: http://emmastoodio.com/GNEUDECK/day-bed.html

Comment: How are you making the thumbnails animate without clicking the left and right arrows? Are you using a plugin, if not can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#left").hide();
$(".thumb").click(function(){
    $("#bigimage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
    $("#bigimage").attr("title", $(this).attr("title"));
    $("#bigimage").attr("alt", $(this).attr("alt"));
});
 //move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button

$("#right").click(function(){
     var maxToLeft=0-$("#thumbnails").width()+$("#thumbnails").parent().width();
     var currentLeft=$("#thumbnails").css('left');
     currentLeft=currentLeft.substring(0,currentLeft.length-2);
     if((parseInt(currentLeft)-185)<=maxToLeft)
     {
     $(this).hide();

      $("#thumbnails").animate({

                 "left": (maxToLeft+178)+"px"

    },500);
     return;
     }
     $("#left").show();
    $("#thumbnails").animate({

        "left": "-=178px"

    },500);

});


 $("#left").click(function(){
var currentLeft=$("#thumbnails").css('left');
 currentLeft=currentLeft.substring(0,currentLeft.length-2);
         if((parseInt(currentLeft)+185)>=20)
         {
         $(this).hide();
         $("#thumbnails").animate({
                 "left": "20px"

},500);
         return;
         }
         $("#right").show();

$("#thumbnails").animate({
    "left": "+=178px"

},500);

 });
 });
```

Comment: thank you! i am new to jquery so it will take me a little while to parse through what you have written. one question: it looks like the right arrow only hides after i click it three times…and is not dependent on the number of thumbnails (which will change depending on the page). Can you point me in the right direction for solving that issue?

Comment: Your #thumbnails element is positioned "absolute", so you have to set its width manually depending on number of thumbnails. Currently you have 1066px for six thumbnails(178 * 6). Increase width of #thumbnails as you increase number of its child. Ex- if there are 10 thumbnails then width should be-  #thumbnails { width:1780px; }

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent their clicks from causing the sliding action if an animation is currently occurring and use the width of the sliding element to determine when sliding is valid.

```
$("#right").click(function(){
    var thumbnails = $("#thumbnails");

    if (thumbnails.is(":animated")) {
        return;
    }

    if ( thumbnails.outerWidth(true) + thumbnails.position().left - 178 > $("#thumbnail-wrapper").innerWidth()) {
        thumbnails.animate({
            "left": "-=178px"           
        },500);
    }
});


$("#left").click(function(){
    var thumbnails = $("#thumbnails");

    if (thumbnails.is(":animated")) {
        return;
    }

    if (thumbnails.position().left < 0) {       
        thumbnails.animate({
            "left": "+=178px"
        },500);
    }
});
```